# Real-time game matchmaking with friends in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, game-center

I would like to implement friends-based matchmaking for a real-time game on iOS 8+

I can already use `GKMatchRequest` to do anonymous matchmaking, but I'm not sure how to let the user attempt to play against someone they already know

Possibilities:

- `GKMatchRequest.recipients` is where you specify players to invite. But where to acquire the `GKPlayer` objects to pass to this property? All I can find is `GKLocalPlayer.loadRecentPlayers()`, which covers only 'someone you have played a game with or a legacy game center friend'.
- `GKMatchMakerViewController` offers a UI for the user to send iMessages to people from Contacts. But the UI is confusing- is there are way to do this programmatically?
- Facebook has what many users would consider their canonical list of friends. Does the Facebook SDK for iOS offer matchmaking against this list? Matchmaking is mentioned for Instant Games, but not mobile games
- 3rd party solution. Perhaps there's another SDK that allows listing of a user's friends/contacts followed by an invitation flow to connect them together?

My ideal UI flow would be

- Tap 'Play against friends'
- Select from a list of your FB friends/iOS contacts
- That user receives an iMessage/FB message from which they can install or open the app
- If you're still waiting for them by the time they launch the app, you are both connected and the game begins

It's been driving me a bit crazy because it seems like quite a common problem - surely many users would want to play against people they know? - but I can't seem to find a clear solution. It doesn't help that the GameCenter APIs seem to have changed a lot and documentation is a bit sparse